# Sending/Saving text on server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Ok please bear with me, I am still a newbie in Razor/JQuery

So in one of my views I need to have a textarea that I need to be able to update without reloading, so I used Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateText", "Car", FormMethod.Post, 
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Car.Text)
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
}
```

The text property is set to `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` so that works fine.
But I need to send the text to the server and save the changes to the database. Can anybody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but I think I do and I wouldn't really recommend the approach you're taking.  But if you really want to do it this way, set the value attribute to the input value before submitting.  Something like this

```
$("#textarr").attr("value", $("#textarr").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to post an ID for the car... in order to know which car's text to update.
If you don't want to display car ID just use an Hidden.

Then, in your controller, you will receive both values: ID and TEXT.  All you need to do now is invoke your database logic to update the car's text.

Comment: The problems where in my model in the end